# Mockito 3 Matcher With Overloaded Method

Tags: java, mockito

Working on migrating from Mockito 1.x to 3.x

If I have a class that declares an overloaded like so:

```
class MyClass {

    public void doSomething(Object o) { ... }
    
    public void doSomething(byte[] bytes) { ... }
}
```

I have problems when trying to verify usage the methods because of type erasure I believe?

When I do:

```
MyClass instance = mock(MyClass.class);
....
verify(instance).doSomething(isA(byte[].class);
```

I run into problems as I'm unable to distinguish between usage of the method that accepts `Object` vs the one that accepts `byte[]`

Comment: Do you want to verify that `doSomething(byte[])` is called and not `doSomething(Object)`? If so, I think this can work: `verify(instance).doSomething(any(byte[].class))`. If you want to retrieve the value, use an `ArgumentCaptor`: `ArgumentCaptor<byte[]> byteCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(byte[].class); verify(instance).doSomething(byteCaptor.capture()); byte[] captured = byteCaptor.getValue();`

Comment: Oh I see! So I should not be using `isA` anymore? That did indeed fix the runtime exception I was getting complaining about the matchers.

Comment: I've never used `isA` before, but I think it can still be used for `instanceof` verification in case there is no overloading.

Comment: I don't see any problem using isA in this case. @thatidiotguy can you provide details on what problem you are facing? Best if you can provide a reproducible example.